# cannot get intersect in worksheet change (ByVal Target as Range) working

Tags: excel, vba

MY code below is supposed to unlock a sheet, unhide columns based on the content of cell K1, and then relock the sheet.  I can get this working using a standard If and IfElse statement, but this then interferes with other macro's which need to lock and unlock cells in the same sheet.  So I thought if I used an event handler this would get round this problem.  But I cannot seem to get it to work or seem to do anything at all.  Any help is as always appreciated as I am still very much a newby and learning all the time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K1")) Is Nothing Then
    If InStr(1, Range("K1"), 1) > 0 Then
    Columns("H:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
    Columns("H:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End If

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me. You haven't been using `Application.EnableEvents` and left it in the `False` state have you?

Comment: Also, where is this code? Make sure it's in the Sheet's code, not a standalone Module.

Comment: If you place the caret inside this procedure and look at the two dropdowns at the top of the code pane, does the left one say "Worksheet" and the right one say "Change"? Or does the left one say "(General)" and the right one says "Worksheet_Change"? If the former, look into `Application.EnableEvents` state; if the latter, move that code to a worksheet module.

Comment: Guys,  All sitting in the actual sheet and not the module. Left one says Worksheet and Right one says Change.      Application.EnableEvents also set to True.  but still nothing happening.    However when I change my original code from Worksheet_SelectionChange to WorkSheet_Change, it works fine without the need to use Intersection, however I suspect that Intersection is a neater and better way to achieve what I am looking for so again any help is appreciated and will be passed on if I ever have the opportunity.

Comment: If you go to cell K1 and type in a new value, does the event handler get called? It won't get called if you just change which cell is selected or if you edit any cell or group of cells that doesn't include K1

Comment: I created a blank workbook and pasted your code into a sheet's code. If I type `0` into `K1` - the columns are un-hidden. If I type `1` into `K1`, the columns hide. If this is not your expected behaviour, tell us what is. Perhaps `K1` contains a formula? If so, then changing *another* cell, that `K1` points to will not work with this code as `K1` itself is not being changed by the user. If that is the case, then you'll need to **store** the previous contents of `K1` and compare it against current contents each time to decide whether to hide the columns or not.